# copy() inserting elements begining of list rather than end

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have the following sample program:

```
10 int main()
11 {
12     list<int> firstlist, secondlist;
13     list<int>::iterator it;
14
15     for (uint32_t i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
16         firstlist.push_back(i);
17         secondlist.push_back(i * 10);
18     }
19
20     it = firstlist.begin();
21     advance(it, 5);
22
23     copy(secondlist.begin(), secondlist.end(), inserter(firstlist, it));
24
25     for (it = firstlist.begin(); it != firstlist.end(); ++it)
26         cout << *it << ' ';
27     cout << endl;
28 }

$ ./t5
10 20 30 40 1 2 3 4
```

Since "it" points to the end of firstlist (line 21), I was expecting the output of lines25/26 to be "1 2 3 4 10 20 30 40", elements of secondlist inserted to the end firstlist.  However, the elements seems to be appended to firstlist (as seen by output).  Can someone please help me understand.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: Duh, should have seen that.  Thank you very much.  Next time please post your response as an answer, so I can upvote your response and mark it as a solution.

Comment: I was getting there. I didn't think it was the answer until I tested it. I guess whatever implementation you use probably implements `std::list` as a cyclic list.

Comment: @chris  So, what is happening under the hood when the third parameter to copy() is invalid.  It seems like appending to firstlist.  I would have expected copy() to overwrite firslist.   Just wondering.

Comment: No guarantees, but the iterator probably ends up back at `firstlist.begin()` due to your implementation. Then, it inserts 10 and moves forward one, just past the 10. Then inserts 20 and so on. The reason it wouldn't overwrite is because that's what `inserter()` is for. It creates an insertion iterator, which inserts elements instead of overwriting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call:

```
advance(it, 5);
```

However, advancing by 4 gets you to `firstlist.end()`. You can't advance further without undefined behaviour.